# Does Twiml require parameters like statusCallBack to be set with the initial use of the conference verb?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

Not long after I started working with Twiml and the conference verb, I found that you could set `maxPartipants`. However, the value would be kept for future uses of the conference verb (for that room), even when `maxPartipants` was not specified.

So some properties are **sticky**

I believe I may be facing a similar issue.

We initially use the conference verb with mute and record and that's all.

Subsequent uses in different calls we set different values, like the status call back.

This was fine in testing as we would never make the initial mute / record call.

I'm just wondering if we don't set the `statusCallback`, `statusCallbackEvent` and `statusCallbackMethod` on the initial use of the conference verb, if this is set in later uses, will these uses be honored instead?

I'm suspecting not ?

I'm not seeing the status calls in our logs at all, in this scenario.

Obviously this is per room.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, the first person to join the conference sets certain conference attributes  for all other participants in that conference like `maxPartipants` or in this case `statusCallback` and `statusCallbackEvent`.

Alan

Comment: It would be great if this could be added to the documentation and which attributes this applies to.